# Origine de « tiens » comme interjection

Tags: sens, interjections, origine-ou-raison

À l'oral, on utilise « tiens » comme interjection, souvent pour introduire un changement de sujet ou peut-être même indiquer un peu de surprise. Par exemple, « tiens, c'est l'heure de manger », « tiens, c'est lui encore ».

Je vois aussi que Joubarc en a parlé pour [traduire *by the way*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/617/929).

Quel est le lien avec tenir ?

Answer (score 3):

Selon le [TLFi (pour le verbe tenir)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tenir) :

> 1. À l'impér. [Fait fonction d'interj. pour exprimer les types d'action d'un locuteur par rapport à une situation donnée] 
>      a) [Sous
>      les formes tiens ou tenez]
>     − [Le locuteur interpelle qqn à qui il
>      présente qqc.] Vous ne voulez pas sortir avec nous? Tenez, voici un
>      livre que j'ai reçu, je pense qu'il vous intéressera (Proust, Sodome,
>      1922, p. 1045).
>     − [Le locuteur active une situation] Bougrelas, le
>      frappant: Tiens, lâche, gueux, sacripant (...)! Père Ubu, ripostant:
>      Tiens! polognard, soûlard, bâtard (...)! (Jarry, Ubu, 1895, v, 2, p.
>      89).
>     − [Le locuteur entre en contact] Ça va bien, dit-il, jetant
>      trente sous sur le comptoir. Tenez, donnez-moi un paquet de cigarettes
>      anglaises (Dorgelès, Croix de bois, 1919, p. 314).
>     − [Le locuteur
>      justifie par un exemple ou par une preuve] Patience, Vial, bientôt je
>      viendrai ici au printemps... et à l'automne... et aussi pendant les
>      mois qui servent à bourrer les intervalles entre deux saisons...
>      février, tiens, ou bien la deuxième quinzaine de novembre (Colette,
>      Naiss. jour, 1928, p. 40).
>     − [Le locuteur défend une opinion] −
>      Honoré! voyons, Honoré... − Et crois-tu que c'est frais? un museau
>      rigoleur... Tiens, pendant qu'on était à causer, je lui ai vu la jambe
>      jusqu'au mollet! Ah! Jésus Fils! Comme c'était! (Aymé, Jument, 1933,
>      p. 193).
>     b) [Uniquement sous la forme tiens]
>     − [Le locuteur exprime sa
>      désapprobation franche, sa rancune] Le prince hindou de l'autre bout
>      de la salle fit un grand geste hautain pour appeler l'infirmier. −
>      Tiens, dit celui-ci au gardien-chef, tu vas voir ce salaud-là! Il a
>      encore recommencé, j'en suis sûr. Oh mais cette fois... (Druon, Gdes
>      fam., t. 2, 1948, p. 250).
>     − [Le locuteur exprime sa surprise dans le
>      discours dir. et dans le discours latent] Je pousse un gémissement;
>      alors il s'arrête, soulève son lorgnon et, par-dessus son journal: −
>      Tiens! Qu'est-ce que tu fais là? Je me crispe (...) et, dans une
>      espèce de sanglot que je voudrais irrésistible: − Je souffre, dis-je
>      (Gide, Si le grain, 1924, p. 426).
>     − [L'empl. de la forme tiens
>      répétée ou suivie de donc signifie que le locuteur retient sa
>      surprise, insinue, ironise] − (...) Voilà le train qui part, vous
>      prendrez le suivant. − Le suivant!... Le suivant!... − Tiens donc!
>      Vous croyez peut-être comme ça q'la compagnie est à vot' disposition?
>      Fallait pas arriver en retard; tant pis pour vous (Courteline, Train 8
>      h. 47, 1888, p. 194).Tiens, tiens, tiens... Est-ce qu'il finirait par
>      s'assagir et comprendre que son bonheur est auprès de sa femme?
>      (Bourdet, Sexe faible, 1931, iii, p. 460).

Answer (score 1):

Tiens, peut être pris dans le sens de *tant que je te tiens* (par la parole, tant que je 
retiens ton attention).

J'apporterais une nuance : il faut qu'il y ait une certaine proximité physique, sociale ou d'intérêt entre les deux personnes (on entend parfois aussi *tenez*) pour l'utiliser.